# drawable left icon becomes invisible?

Tags: android

I have added drawable left and right icon to edittext. Drawable right use to show or hide password but when I click on drawable right icon, drawable left becomes invisible.How to solve this issue?

```
txtPassword.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (event.getRawX() >= (txtPassword.getRight() - txtPassword.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                    if (IsHidePwd) {
                        txtPassword.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_show_pwd, 0);
                        txtPassword.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());

                        IsHidePwd = false;
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        txtPassword.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_hide_pwd, 0);
                        txtPassword.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());

                        IsHidePwd = true;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: try to give size to txtPassword.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(10, 10, R.drawable.ic_show_pwd, 10);
it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line i think you need to set drawable for left side also.

txtPassword.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.left_img, 0, R.drawable.ic_show_pwd, 0);